# Python programming language login error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm an absolute beginner to Python, but I have used visual basic.net a little. I'm currently working on a login using a pair of lists as a form of database but I'm receiving an error when running the module. Like I said I'm an absolute beginner so it is probably something stupid, but any help resolving this error would be really appreciated, thank you!

Here is the *.py file:

```
username = ["nathan","george"]
password = ["password","password"]

usrindex = 0
psswrdindex = 0

usrnm = input("username:")
while usrindex < len(usrnm):
    if username[usrindex] == usrnm 
    Then psswrd = input("password:")
        while psswrdindex < len(psswrd):
            if password[psswrdindex] == psswrd
                Then print("Success")
                Else psswrdindex = psswrdindex + 1
    Else usrindex = usrindex + 1
print("Failure")
```

When I try to run the module in IDLE, it says that the syntax is invalid and highlights
this line:

```
if username[usrindex] == usrnm
```

Like I said, any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I recommend reading a basic python tutorial. You are mistaking the python syntax

Answer (score 4):

You need a colon at the end:

```
if username[usrindex] == usrnm:
```

Course, that only fixes the `SyntaxError`.  You're also gonna get a ton of `NameError`s because your code isn't really Python.  It will blow up saying that `Else` and `Then` aren't defined.

Python if-statements are composed like this:

```
if condition:
    ...
elif condition:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Here is what I think you actually need:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

This goes over all the basics in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a colon at the end of the line:

```
 if username[usrindex] == usrnm:
```

Answer (score 0):

Python syntax for the `if` block:

```
if condition:
    statement
else:
    statement
```

Answer (score 0):

You must learn python syntax.

might be useful to learn,

```
username = ["nathan","george"]
password = ["password","password"]

usrindex = 0
psswrdindex = 0

usrnm = raw_input("username:")
success = False
while usrindex < len(username):
    if username[usrindex] == usrnm:
        psswrd = raw_input("password:")
        while psswrdindex < len(password):
            if password[psswrdindex] == psswrd:
                print("Success")
                success = True
                break
            else:
                psswrdindex = psswrdindex + 1
        break
    else:
        usrindex = usrindex + 1

if not success:
    print("Failure")
```